# greedy algorithms

Tags: algorithm, greedy

I am new to algorithms and am currently studying using you-tube video tutorials/lectures and a book, I firstly watch the video and then read the book and finally try a question from the book to make sure I have learned the topic correctly. I am currently up to greedy algorithms and it is very confusing.

Inside the book there are various problems but I am having trouble understanding and answering a particular one.

Firstly it gives the problem which is (I've just copied the text).

there is a set of n objects of sizes {x1; x2;..... xn} and a bin with
capacity B. All these are positive integers. Try to find a subset of these objects
so that their total size is smaller than or equal to B, but as close to B as possible.

All objects are 1-dimensional. For example, if the objects have sizes 4, 7, 10, 12, 15, and
B = 20, then we should choose 4 and 15 with total size 19 (or equivalently, 7 and 12).
For each of the following greedy algorithms, show that they are not optimal by creating
a counter-example. try to make your examples as bad as you can, where "badness"
is measured by the ratio between the optimal and greedy solutions. Thus if the best
solution has value 10 and the greedy solution has value 5, then the ratio is 2.

how do I do this for the following?

1) Always choose the object with the largest size so that the total size of this and all
other objects already chosen does not exceed B. Repeat this for the remaining objects.

Comment: ive tried to create a modified "prims algorithm" for a solution to this question but it is very messy and probably incorrect.

Comment: Prim's algorithm builds a spanning tree in a graph. Perhaps you want to explain how this algorithm is suitable for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the following instance of the problem:

You have a box of size `2n`, one element of size `n+1` and the rest are of size `n`.

It is easy to see that the optimal is 2 elements of size `n`, while the greedy will get you one element of size `n+1`.

Since it is true for each `n`, it actually gives you a desired ratio of at least using this greedy approach `2`.

Comment: what would this look like in pseudocode, as this helps me understand it better.

Comment: @user1252908: What pseudo-code? The counter example? it is just an array of elements... I am not sure I am following you..

Comment: Doh! sorry I see, been studying this for 4 hours straight!!!. thank you for the explanation.

Comment: 1 last question, what if we Try all pairs of objects and find the pair that has the maximum total size that is still
at most B. then use your above method to fill the remaining space if there is any.

Comment: @user1252908: Ratio of 4/3 is easy to see: assume `B=4n`, and 4 boxes of size `n` and 4 boxes of size `n+1`. The optimal solution is 4 boxes of `n`, while the algorithm will yield 2 boxes of size `n+1` and one box of `n`, so total of `3n+2`, and a ratio of `4n/(3n+2)`. Since it is true for every `n`, you get ratio of 4/3. I Believe you can find a counter-example with "higher" ratio, but I am not sure.

Comment: @amit instead of B=4n, do B=3n and you get ratio of 3/2 which I think is the maximum achievable ratio.

Comment: @ElKamina: Thanks, I didn't put too much thaught on it, but it is obvious when you see it! [makes me want to bump my head into the wall for not seeing it myself]

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similar to the 0-1 Knapsack problem where each item has a different size but the same value, which means any one item doesn't have any preference to being placed into the bin other than its size.  In your code, you need to examine each item and calculate the maximum total size that results whether or not putting it into the bin without exceeding the capacity of the bin.